# OOP implementation of a forum

Tags: php, oop, open-source, forum

I've been searching for this and can't quite get to what I need.

Is anyone aware of an open source forum script written in PHP that utilizes OOP concepts?

So has to be

1. Forum
2. OOP
3. Open source

I will accept answers for anything else, including tutorials, videos, etc. since I get to still see the source and learn from it.

Comment: which have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

I have used PHPBB in the past and it appears to fit your needs.

> phpBB is a free flat-forum bulletin
>   board software solution that can be
>   used to stay in touch with a group of
>   people or can power your entire
>   website. With an extensive database of
>   user-created modifications and styles
>   database containing hundreds of style
>   and image packages to customise your
>   board, you can create a very unique
>   forum in minutes.
>
> No other bulletin board software
>   offers a greater complement of
>   features, while maintaining efficiency
>   and ease of use. Best of all, phpBB is
>   completely free. We welcome you to
>   test it for yourself today*. If you
>   have any questions please visit our
>   Community Forum where our staff and
>   members of the community will be happy
>   to assist you with anything from
>   configuring the software to modifying
>   the code for individual needs. Learn
>   more about phpBB.

You can find it at:

http://www.phpbb.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/).

It's free, open-source and does not have the bloat as many of its competitors (vB, phpBB) and it also has some very well written code to go alongside a *reasonably* good documentation =)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can find a convenient open source forum software at:
http://www.forummatrix.org/

You could try Viscacha (http://www.forummatrix.org/show/Viscacha).